# display files and folders in php (file handeling)

Tags: php

i want to display files and folders folders should have "+" beside it and a file should have a "-" sign beside it 
+Folder
 -file
this is what i have so far

```
  function listFolderFiles($dir){
   $ffs = scandir($dir);

   unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
   unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

   // prevent empty ordered elements
   if (count($ffs) < 1)
       return;


   foreach($ffs as $ff){
       echo '+'.$ff ."<br>";
       if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);

   }

}

listFolderFiles('C:\xampp\htdocs\ic');
```

Comment: Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
   $ffs = scandir($dir);

   unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
   unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

   // prevent empty ordered elements
   if (count($ffs) < 1)
       return;

   foreach($ffs as $ff){       
       if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
          echo '+'.$ff ."<br>";
          listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
       } else {
          echo '-'.$ff ."<br>";
       }
   }
}

listFolderFiles('C:\xampp\htdocs\ic');
```